# How do read/interact with an old ActiveX SSUltraGrid using UIAutomation

Tags: c#, com, activex, ui-automation

I am investigating automated testing of an old Win32 application that used ActiveX controls. I am spiking use White (from Thougthworks) that uses Microsoft UIAutomation. I can find the AutomationElement related to the control, but how do I interact with it?

Spy++ sees the grid control as a single window, so I can't talk to rows, columns, or cells directly. How do I talk to the SSUltraGrid control from my test code?

Cheers
Nigel

Comment: What is the UIAutomation ControlType of your grid control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem with some ActiveX and other custom controls like SSUltraGrid is what you mentioned, they're presented as just one window.  So unless they've provided an API that makes them "friendly" to your GUI automation tool, you'll always face this challenge.  Of course many companies offer newer versions of their products that are friendlier to UI Automation than before... perhaps upgrading the control is worthwhile...

Failing that... what the test engineers at my job have told me is that when they encounter that situation, if there are well known keystrokes to invoke the activity they desire, they send keystrokes to the control window.  If they're lucky enough to have things in a fixed location, they might even be able to get away with sending mouse events.  However, that's dicey at best.